# C++ rendering shapes

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I'm trying to generate shapes within a specific area. the game i am making has a resolution of 1024x768 but the game board occupies only 768x768 in the centre of the screen.

Currently, i can get the shapes to randomly generate and not exceed the MAXIMUM_WIDTH and MAXIMUM_HEIGHT constraints. However, the shapes can still render too far left which is off the game board. I tried adding MINIMUM_WIDTH and MINUMUM_HEIGHT but i'm not sure where to apply this in the x= and y= stage

I've included the relevant code below.

What can i add/modify to this code to make the shapes be limited to the game board?

Thanks.

```
const size_t MaxShapes {5};
const unsigned int MaxScale {5};
const unsigned int MINIMUM_WIDTH = 128;
const unsigned int MAXIMUM_WIDTH = 896;
const unsigned int MINUMUM_HEIGHT = 0;
const unsigned int MAXIMUM_HEIGHT = 768;

bool PlayState::onCreate()
{
    snakes_.push_back(new AISnake);
    snakes_.back()->setPosition(Position(40,40));
    snakes_.push_back(new PlayerSnake);
    snakes_.back()->setPosition(Position(20,20));

    double x, y;
    for(unsigned shape = 0;shape < MaxShapes;shape++)
    {
        x = (double)(rand() % MAXIMUM_WIDTH);
        y = (double)(rand() % MAXIMUM_HEIGHT);

        shapes_.push_back(Triangle({x, y}));

    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try

```
x = (double)((rand() % (MAXIMUM_WIDTH - MINIMUM_WIDTH)) + MINIMUM_WIDTH);
y = (double)((rand() % (MAXIMUM_HEIGHT - MINIMUM_HEIGHT)) + MINIMUM_HEIGHT);
```

Say you want to find a random number between 5 and 15. The difference between 5 and 15 is 10. So you first find a random number between 0 and 10 and then add that to 5 to bring it back into the proper range (between 5 and 15).

Comment: Thank you so much! that worked a treat. Don't suppose you would know how to prevent them from possibly overlapping?

Comment: You should probably post that as a separate question. Just make sure to give the question some thought and include what you have tried (like you did with this question).

Comment: If I answered your question, would you mind accepting the answer? :)

Comment: sure, i'll have a try at preventing overlap and create a new post if i'm unable to. Thanks for your answer :)